Is Old Church Slavonic съпрѧтьнъ (sŭprętĭnŭ) descending from PIE *sprend-, *sprendʰ- *sper- (“to flinch; jump”)?
It has always intrigued me that the rather popular Romanian word sprinten (swift, fast, lively) seems very close semantically to English sprint.
The etymology of the English word is rather detailed on Wiktionay, going back to a PIE root:

English sprint Alteration of earlier sprent (“to leap; bound;
dart”), from Northern Middle English sprenten, from Old Norse *sprenta
(for later spretta), from Proto-Germanic *sprantijaną, causative of
Proto-Germanic *sprintaną (“to jump up; bounce”), from
Proto-Indo-European *sprend-, *sprendʰ- (“to flinch; jump”), from
Proto-Indo-European *sper- (“to twitch; fidget; flinch; jump; be
quick”). Cognate with Middle High German sprenzen (“to sprinkle;
splash”), Swedish spritta (“to startle”), Icelandic spretta (“to
spring forth; emerge; arise; develop”).

That of the Romanian is less so, and it only goes back to Old Slavonic:

Borrowed from Old Church Slavonic съпрѧтьнъ (sŭprętĭnŭ). Compare
Serbo-Croatian spretan, Slovene spreten, Bulgarian спретен (spreten).

The link for Old Church Slavonic съпрѧтьнъ (sŭprętĭnŭ) link is void, and the others don't give any etymology.
Is the Slavic sŭprętĭnŭ descending from the same PIE root?
Romanian has also the (to me) obviously related word sprințar, ”sprightly”. The fact that it is not marked as related to sprinten in the dictionaries seems to be an omission/lacuna, although they are marked as synonyms. Sprinten=”one that runs fast”, sprințar=”one that runs/jumps fast in all directions”, while -ar/țar is a normal Romanian suffix: dinte (tooth) > dințar (tool for adjusting the teeth of a saw), cârnat (sausage) > cârnățar (sausage-maker).
(I need to know this before asking myself whether the Germanic root might have resulted in the Romanian word without a Slavic intermediary - which would be an exceptional occurrence, but not unique).

It doesn’t seem likely. As best I can tell, OCS sъprętьnъ appears to be derived from the verb sъprętati ‘keep back, restrain’, in turn from prętati ‘suppress, check’ (‘restraintful’ → ‘dexterous, skill’?). LIV² has OCS +pręnǫti as being from this root (with various possible prefixes), as well as +prędati – that would be expected from a root ending in *-d⁽ʰ⁾-, but +prętati with a t would be hard to explain. Unfortunately, no OCS form matching -pręt- appears in LIV².

@JanusBahsJacquet - could you post that as a NO answer (not just comment)? It makes the Slavic root less probable, which it already is, because: (1) of the -nt- sound absent in all Slavic variants, (2) of the semantic divergence (‘keep back, restrain’ resulting in ”fast, sprightly”? - with no shade of the ”dexterous” meaning in Romanian forms), (3) of the better alternatives - the Germanic sprintaną, if not even of a similar Latin development as for English sprightly-sprite-esprit-spiritus, given Romanian spiriduș (elf, pixie) and the expression ”ca un spiriduș”, like a... = "fast")

I’m hesitant to post an answer, since I’m not quite sure sъprętьnъ is actually from sъprętati – it seems likely, but I’ve no sources for it. I’m also not convinced your first two points are very strong: [1] there are other OCS nasal vowels borrowed as /Vn/ in Romanian (e.g., obrinti, pinten); [2] the other Slavic forms mean ‘dexterous, skilful, adroit’, and it’s a very short way from ‘adroit’ to ‘agile’, or from ‘skilful’ to ‘smart, keen’ – certainly no worse than from ‘jump, leap, bounce’.
